# Error when mapping to case class from Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have no idea why this doesn't work.  If instead of mapping to my case class I just return a tuple, it works fine.  Otherwise, I get the error below.

```
case class WinRate(name: String, played: Int, wins: Int, losses: Int)    
val winners = df.select($"winning_heroes").map(row => {
      row.getList[String](0).toList().map(x => {
        WinRate(x, 1, 1, 0)
      })
    }).flatMap(x => x)
```

Error: not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)String in trait LinearSeqOptimized. Unspecified value parameter n.

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? Doing `map` and `flatMap` seems very...well...weird these days given how much Spark SQL offers out of the box (cf. standard functions).

Comment: My database has an array field of strings.  So, I'm pulling out the strings and creating a tuple(trying to do case class instead above) for each one of those.  Then I'm doing a .groupBy and sum to get win rates.  I've got it working with tuples, just wanted to do it with case classes as it seems a bit nicer/easier to read.  I'm pretty new to scala so there are probably better/more idiomatic ways of doing it.

Comment: Edit your question to include `df.printSchema` to make the question easier to answer. Thanks.

Comment: And if you include input samples and expected result, then you should be getting better suggestions quickly

Answer (score 1):

How is the toList() method defined? Can you try calling it without the paranthesis?

```
row.getList[String](0).toList
```

Comment: I get a different error.   Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.